# Copy record from one table to another which has one more column

Tags: sqlite

TABLE one:

```
A B C
```

TABLE two:

```
A B D C
```

As you can see column D was added to the middle.

How to copy record from table one to table two setting value D to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `D` in the list of columns of `Table2`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(A, B, C)
SELECT A, B, C FROM Table1
```

Maybe you need a `WHERE` clause also if you want to copy a specific row only.
`D` will get its default value, if there is one defined in the `CREATE` statement of `Table2`, or `null` if there isn't a default value.

Comment: What if column D set NOT NULL?

Comment: If it is defined as set NOT NULL and there isn't defined a default value then you will get an error and the row will not be inserted.

Comment: I know, how to handle that case? I doubt `INSERT INTO Table2(A, B, C, D)
SELECT A, B, C FROM Table1, "new D value"` will work.

Comment: INSERT INTO Table2(A, B, C, D) SELECT A, B, C, "new D value" FROM Table1

Comment: Super. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, it's better to use single quotes for string literals.